Deriving and calling key value pairs from deserialized JSON data in Kotlin
I have a program that receives JSON data after a request to a third party API. I need to be able to call the values using the keys that I've deserialized. I know that the method lies in kotlins Map<> function. However, I keep getting the same error:
Error: Unexpected JSON token at offset 14: Expected start of the array '[', but had '1' instead at path: $['userId']

    const val TAG = "MainActivity"

    @Serializable
    data class JSONdata(@SerialName("userId")val userId: Int,
                    @SerialName("id")val id: Int,
                    @SerialName("title")val title: String,
                    @SerialName("completed")val completed: Boolean)



   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


   private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

   private val httpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json{
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })

            install(Logging){logger = Logger.DEFAULT
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        coroutineScope.launch {

            try {
                val posts = httpClient.get { url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
                                    }    
                val postsResponse = posts.bodyAsText()
                val parent = Json{ignoreUnknownKeys = true}.decodeFromString<Map<String,List<JSONdata>>>(postsResponse)                             

                                                                                                        
                val parentID = parent.get("title")

                println(parentID)


            }   catch(e: RedirectResponseException){
                // 3xx - responses
                println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
            }   catch(e: ClientRequestException){
                // 4xx - responses
                println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
            }   catch(e: ServerResponseException){
                //3xx - responses
                println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
            }   catch(e: Exception){
                println("Error: ${e.message}")
            }

            httpClient.close()
        }
      }
    }


I have tried putting the Map in both the data class and decodeFromString function but keep getting this recurring error. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
